# Why isn’t the definite article used in "The commission commanded that work [...] should cease"?

Tags: meaning, definite-articles, zero-article

In this sentence:

> The commission commanded that **work** on the building should cease.

Why isn't *the* used before the word *work*? It seems that the work is specified by *on the building*.

Another example is,

> **Construction** of the building will start next week.

I understand construction here is something like putting up the building,
and so the construction isn’t general in meaning. But the definite article isn’t used here, either.

I’ve asked about this several times, but none gave me a good answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use (or non-use) of articles before abstract nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/use-or-non-use-of-articles-before-abstract-nouns)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be given an answer that really satisfies you and leaves you happy. English is quirky. I'm sure that some natural speakers would prefer _construction ..._ to _the construction ..._ here, in ordinary conversation (headlinese tends to omit articles anyway), but _the building of the bridge ..._ to _building of the bridge ..._.  Your first example sounds more idiomatic without the article (which would not however be wrong here) - possibly because the expression 'start work on ...' is so well known.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth I feel the same. English is quirky, but any language would be, even my mother tongue. No one except you have replied, which seems that my question is some hard to explain. Any opinions are ok, so I'd like everyone to leave anything that could be reasonable. I want to have a guess at this with more clues. Thanks @Edwin Ashworth. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can come up with, is that different people view "work" on a building (and "construction" *of* a building) in different ways.

One who uses the article views the work process as collective. In other words, we are all working together on this building. The construction of this building requires a single collective work effort. The phrase, "the work", best describes this.

On the other hand, one who chooses to use no article is using "work" as a mass noun (which generally lack an article, as in the case of the word water: "the glass is filled with water", vs. "the glass is filled with *the* water"... the latter sounds awkward, unless you are referring to a specific source of water), and they are trying to encompass not only the greater collective "work" that is being done, but the individual "work" being performed by each individual member of a crew.

In this particular case, in the first example, they want to make sure that nobody is doing anything to work on that building, and so, rather than viewing all work on the building as a single "work", they are viewing it as a plural, with masons, bricklayers, carpenters, plumbers, etc. providing individual work.

The same principal applies in the second example, with it viewed as a process of a collaborative effort made up of everyone's individual efforts, rather than as a singular collective effort.

Really, there is no real reason why it is written this way, except, perhaps, as a "politically correct" way of appeasing workers who are putting a great deal of effort into a project. Whether or not anyone actually picks up on this is debatable; however, you will find the article-less "work" used *far* more uniformly in announcements made to workers than in announcements made to those for whom the building is being worked on and in literature.

Comment: Your explanation does make sense to me. I think you could show a few more examples or words used that way, if you would do me one more favor. I'm really happy to get a good clue to my question. Thank you very much @Cmillz!

Comment: I'm not sure there are a lot of other examples quite like this, unfortunately, simply because work is a mass noun.

However, it would be similar to saying "The banana is a vital part of a monkey's diet," as opposed to "Bananas are a vital part of a monkey's diet." The former puts emphasis on the banana as a type of fruit, whereas the latter puts more emphasis on individual bananas and each banana's nutritional value, independent from other bananas.

Comment: Actually, the best example is probably a questionable one, so don't hold this against me, please...

It is the difference between saying "Hitler tried to kill the Jewish people," vs. "Hitler tried to kill Jewish people." The latter sounds far more personal, doesn't it? It brings to mind individual people, rather than a group of people.

Comment: In that context, "the Jewish people" means *all* Jews, the entire nation or race or culture of Jews. But "Jewish people" refers to some Jews (plural), not necessarily all. Maybe as few as two. That is why the former is a stronger statement.

Comment: How would I hold that against you? I'm really feeling so good. Many thanks to you, @Cmillz! How hard you were to type up all the things! Your nickname is hard to type, @MετάEd, and your supplement to Cmilz's comment is as good as sure. Thanks!

Comment: Ascribing this to political correctness strains credulity! Plus, this answer is full of errors and unsupported claims: 1. "Water" is a mass noun whether "the" precedes it or not. 2. "Collaborative effort" and "collective effort" can't be considered much different. 3. "Work" used without "the" is found a _huge_ number of times in _many_ contexts, especially in public announcements, thus refuting your claim. 4. "Making sure that nobody is doing any work" is not in some way assured by not using "the." That would be accomplished by specific orders conveyed directly from management to workers.

Comment: 1. I was using water to explain what a mass noun was, and that mass nouns often lack articles in and of themselves. Perhaps that was unnecessary and/or poorly placed.

2. There isn't much difference in the tone of the sentences. One puts more emphasis on the individual work than the other.

3. I did not say that work without "the" was never found in many contexts, I said that work is found almost 100% of the time without the article in a for-workers context.

4. Yeah, that's a valid point. I still think the connotative notion is there, but I'm not opposed to deleting that.

Comment: As for credulity, KSS asked for opinions so I provided one. There is a reason that the particular word is used in such a way. Frankly, I am not convinced that the rules of abstract nouns are the only factor in play here, because, as KSS noted, the work IS specified by the context, "on the building". "The work" actually DOES encompass the entire structure, and I see no reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @MετάEd, that's the point of what I was trying to say, more or less. "The work" refers to the entire work, while "work" denotes the components, down to the smallest point.

Answer (score 1):

We use "the work" to indicate some particular work, some specified project on one portion of the edifice, such as (for example) replacing the walls in one office, or repairing the elevators. For this reason, we really never say "the work *on* the building," because "the work" doesn't encompass the entire structure, whereas "on" the building does generally imply we are talking about the entire structure. If we were referring to a specific project, such as replacing the elevators, we might say "the work *being done* on the building."

"*Work* on the building" is used almost exclusively to refer to the totality of all work involved in *constructing* a building. In other words, it stands in for "building the building," which we don't say because of the awkwardness of repeating the word "building." We might also use "work on the building" it if the work involved really is work that affects the entire building, such as a complete, massive renovation.

Comment: It's not a geeky; it's perfectly reasonable. The second sentence is essentially the same case. "The construction" is used to mean "a specified sub-portion." "Construction" means "the entire process of building it." It's conceptual, rather than specific. You're right about "the students," because it's not a mass noun. There's also the fact that "the construction" CAN be used to mean "all;" there's no hard-and-fast rule. But there are multiple reasons for saying something a particular way, and the simple fact that "the construction of the building" uses "the" twice is reason enough to drop one.

Comment: Your explanation's different to Cmilz's. As far as I know, the definite article narrows down the range of the modified noun. For example, in 'the students in this class', the students means all the students in the class. My guess was that the work referred to the whole process of putting up the building. I'm not a native speaker and so I'm getting confused! And I wonder yours also goes with the second question, 'construction of the building will start next week'. Even if yours or Cmilz's might be wrong, I'm very grateful to you all for paying attention to my geeky question!

Comment: I happened to click the delete button. Yes, I've got the same idea. There are always a lot of ways to get across one's feelings in language, and must be reasons for why some way should be used, making perfect rules out of them will never be possible, though. But seeking for those are all I want to do, and you've much helped me with one of those. :) I'd like you to help me in the future. Thanks!